# How do I make my string that is connected to mapping display in my Label?

Tags: ios, swift

I am coding an app to take a string of letters and separate them into 3 letter groups, then to essentially convert those groups to a specified word with `mapping`and I have done this right.  But now, I need to get the end of my code from a `print()` command to a `Label.text =` command.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func decBttn(_ sender: Any) {
    var textField:String
    let mapping = [
          "aaa" :
             "Lysine" ,
          "aag" :
             "Lysine" ,
          "aac" :
             "Asparagine" ,
          // lots more here
    ]

    let characters = textField.characters

    var index = 0

    while index < characters.count {
        let start = textField.index(textField.startIndex, offsetBy: index)

        var endOffset = index+3
        if index+3 > characters.count {
            endOffset = characters.count
        }

        let end = textField.index(textField.startIndex, offsetBy: endOffset)
        let range = start..<end

        let groupedSubstring = textField[range]

        print(mapping [groupedSubstring] ?? groupedSubstring)
        index = index + 3
```

This is the code I am working with, any ideas?

Comment: So you don't know know to install a string into a label? That's what your question seems to boil down to.

You've created a dictionary and try to map 3-character strings from an input field into keys from your dictionary.

You've written code that loops through the input in 3-character chunks. Do you want to combine the results of mapping each 3-character group in your label, so you might get get "SerineArginineValineHistidine" out of a 12-character input string?

Comment: If you write your code to install each mapped string in turn into your label, you would end up installing a variety of different strings into your label that you would never see, then finally your label would contain the last result.

Comment: I want to make the mapped string return the 12 character string with a word on each line and the label is set correctly for that.  So how do I install the string looped by 3 character chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want your destination view to be a `UITextView`, not a label. `UITextViews` are multi-line by default, and support scrolling.

Use code like this:

```
var output = ""

while index < characters.count {
    let start = textField.index(textField.startIndex, offsetBy: index)

    var endOffset = index+3
    if index+3 > characters.count {
        endOffset = characters.count
    }

    let end = textField.index(textField.startIndex, offsetBy: endOffset)
    let range = start..<end

    let groupedSubstring = textField[range]

    output += mapping[groupedSubstring] ?? groupedSubstring + "\n"
    index = index + 3
}
outputView.text = output
```

(rewritten to use an output `IBOutlet` of `outputView` since that name would work for an output UILabel as in your question, or a UITextView (my suggestion)

(Note that you could rewrite the above to be much more concise using `stride()` and `map()`, but that's likely beyond your current skill level so I won't go there.)

#### EDIT:

Rewriting your loop code using functional programming style:

First, create an extension to String: (This code should probably be in it's own file, and should not be inside the definition of another object.)

```
///String extension to add `chunkBy(_:)`
extension String {
  
  /**
   This function breaks a string into an array of chunks of size chunkSize (the last entry may be shorter)
   - Parameters:
     - chunkSize: The size of the chunks
   - Returns: An array of strings
 */
  func chunkBy(_ chunkSize: Int) -> [String] {
    //Create an array of starting indexes for each output chunk
    let indexes = stride(from: 0, to: input.count, by: chunkSize)
    
    //Map the array of start index values into an array of substrings of chunkSize.
    let result: [String] = indexes.map {
      let startIndex = input.index(input.startIndex, offsetBy: $0)
      let endIndex = input.index(input.startIndex, offsetBy: $0 + chunkSize, limitedBy: input.endIndex) ?? input.endIndex
      let substring = input[startIndex..<endIndex]
      return String(substring)
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Now here is the code that would go inside your view controller's string parsing method:

```
var input = "aaaaacaagxyza" //This is test data; You'd use user input.

let mapping = [
  "aaa" :
  "Lysine" ,
  "aag" :
  "Lysine" ,
  "aac" :
  "Asparagine" ,
  // lots more here
]


let result = input.chunkBy(3)
  .map { mapping[$0, default: $0] } //Map the array of chunks to dictionary lookups, or use the original if none found
  
  //Use the reduce function to collapse the array of strings into one string with newlines.
  .reduce ("",{ $0 + $1 + "\n" })

print (result)
//Now install your result into your text view.
```

Comment: So, what goes in the var output = "" ? Would I use the same content within let mapping = ?I am quite new to code and its a learning experience for me between school and other responsibilities, thank you for helping!

Comment: Look at the changes I made. I define an empty var `output`. Then in the `while` loop I append each mapped string (plus a newline at the end), to the output string. Once you exit the while loop, you install the contents of output into the text field's text property.

Comment: It's odd because the code line `let result = input.chunkBy(3)` Comes back with the error  `Value of type String has no member  chunkBy` Even through `func chunkBy()` is clearly stated

Comment: The String extension that contains chunkBy has to be at the top level, not inside a class.

Comment: So you went for the 2nd, functional programming approach? If I've answered your question you should accept my answer, and if you feel I've been a big help you should think about up-voting me once you have enough reputation to do so. (Accepting the best answer that solves your problem is a must. Up-voting is purely optional, but considered good form for helpful answers.)